# calculate pixel by pixel mean of the rasters using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

Since the two rasters (raster1 and raster2) overlap each other, I want to make new raster by calculating mean of each overlapped pixels; i.e., The resulting new  raster is calculated as:

```
new = [[mean(1,3), mean(1,3), mean(1,3), mean(1,3), mean(1,3)],[mean(2,4),mean(2,4),mean(2,4),mean(2,4),mean(2,4)]]


import numpy as np    
raster1 = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2]])
raster2 = np.array([[3,3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4,4]])

new = np.mean(raster1,raster2,axis=1)
print (new.tolist())
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe I misunderstood you but do you want?

```
raster = (raster1 + raster2) / 2
```

Actually in this case you don't even need `np.mean`, just use matrix operations.

`np.mean` is used to deal with calculating mean for a single matrix on specific axis, so it is a different situation.

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
new = np.mean([raster1,raster2],axis=1)
```

with brackets. Actually I am guessing it should be
It should be

```
new = np.mean([raster1,raster2],axis=0)
```

The first argument to np.mean should be the whole array, see e.g. http://wiki.scipy.org/Numpy_Example_List_With_Doc#mean