# array manipulation in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

How to obtain new array (new) from original array (x) by calculating mean as follows:

```
new = [[mean(1,3), mean(1,3), mean(1,3), mean(1,3), mean(1,3)],[mean(2,4),mean(2,4),mean(2,4),mean(2,4),mean(2,4)]]


import numpy as np

arr1 = np.array([[1,1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2,2]])
arr2 = np.array([[3,3,3,3,3],[4,4,4,4,4]])
my_array = np.array([arr1,arr2])

for x in my_array:    
    new = np.mean(x,axis=1)
    print (new)
```

IMPORTANT:
The arr1, arr2, and my_array are not really available as inputs, what is available is only x. So, the real data to be manipulated are in the form of for loop given by x as shown above.

Comment: What keeps you asking again without updating the original question? [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516643/calculate-pixel-by-pixel-mean-of-the-rasters-using-numpy/20516933#20516933)

Comment: @ Ray IMPORTANT: The arr1, arr2, and my_array are not really available as inputs, what is available is only x. So, the real data to be manipulated are in the form of for loop given by x as shown above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given `my_array` as defined above

```
>>> my_array
array([[[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3, 3, 3],
        [4, 4, 4, 4, 4]]])
```

You simply need to take the mean over the first axis as follows:

```
>>> my_array.mean(axis=0)
array([[ 2.,  2.,  2.,  2.,  2.],
       [ 3.,  3.,  3.,  3.,  3.]])
```

If it must be iterative for subsequent `x` you could do the following:

```
sums = 0
counter = 0
for x in my_array:
  sums += x
  counter += 1
new = sums / counter
```

Or, if you can store the data:

```
data = []
for x in my_array:
  data.append(x)
new = np.dstack(data).mean(axis=2)
```

Comment: @ rroowwllaanndd thanks for your efforts. however, the arr1 and arr2 are not really available as inputs, what is available is x.

Comment: @ rroowwllaanndd The arr1, arr2, and my_array are not really available as inputs, what is available is only x. So, the real data to be manipulated are in the form of for loop given by x as shown above.

Comment: @ rroowwllaanndd IMPORTANT: The arr1, arr2, and my_array are not really available as inputs, what is available is only x. So, the real data to be manipulated are in the form of for loop given by x as shown above.

Comment: Ah - I see what you’re after now - see my last edit!

Comment: @  rroowwllaanndd yes, thanks, upvoted and accepted it was what i am looking for thanks